# regexp in expect?

Tags: regex, expect

how do i get a pattern like this splitted into 3 variables using regex in expect?

```
set var Gi1/0/23
```

please help and explain?

**regexp pattern $var a b c**

such that

```
a --> Gi1
b --> 0
c --->23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work to capture target input in 3 groups:

```
(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)
```

FYI `\w` means "word char", ie `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so it should work for a variety of input.

Comment: Since this is for expect, I just wanted to expand.  I used @Bohemian's answer to get this to work: `expect -re {^Problem\sstreams\s=\s((\d[\s]?)+$)}` which matches the "0 1 2 3 4" in the string "Problem streams = 0 1 2 3 4", for example.  I could then assign that match to a variable as such: `set mydigits expect_out(0,string)`.  The outer parens match the entire string of digits and spaces between them.  The inner parens match each digit as it comes across it so by the end, it equals "4", using my string as the example.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex would capture `Fa*number*` or `Gi*number*` in back-reference group 1 and the last number in back-reference group 2

```
^((?:Fa|Gi)\d)/\d+/(\d+)
```

**Update:**

Based on your updated question, something like this would capture your generic pattern:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually go by this rule-of-thumb: if you know what you want to keep, use a regex; if you know what you want to throw away, use split. Here, you know you want to use slash as a separator and get the leftover values, so I'd use split.

```
split $var /
```

To assign the resulting values to variables, use one of these forms:

```
lassign [split $var /] a b c             ;# for recent versions of expect
foreach {a b c} [split $var /] {break}   ;# for old versions
```